# My colleauge is bothering me

Tags: management

I work in a small company from last 4 years as a Reporting  Specialist, I was the only female in the company,other people working for this company are mostly guys. I was overloaded from work so when I ask my boss to quit the company he decided to split my job in two and he hired a new girl for all Admin and Adhoc requests. Since the new girl came, she started to complaint about me, and funniest thing that my boss whom I work with is become very nasty with me. He started insulted and put me down in front of her. I tried my best to talk to my boss personally and also with new girl, but every thing getting worse. My boss doesn't seems to trust on me anymore. He started bad mouthing against me in the office. As a result my Director and other people got impression that I am doing something wrong with new girl. I really don't know how to resolve this issue, I am getting reaction from most of my management only because my boss have wrong assumptions about me. I am not feeling good because of this stress. I am only thinking to quit this company. Other wise I have to face different issues everyday. Please someone help me.

Comment: As a woman in the workforce you should understand how very insulting it is to call people girl. No one in the workplace is a girl. They are adults.

Comment: Is this a question or a rant?

Comment: I see a whole post full of opinions and conclusions. There are no facts and there is no question. Please [edit your question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/35728/edit) to improve it. That includes removing the [wall of text](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wall%20of%20text) so that it is easier for other to read it. That helps *you* getting answers.

Answer (score 3):

I see several possibilities.

The first is that you need to learn to play office politics and the new employee is currently using them against you and you need to learn how to fight back and restore your reputation. Likely she is aiming at your job. You should probably get a good book on office politics and read it throroughly and practice what it says. The subject is pretty complex and I can't write a thorough answer on a forum like this. At a minimum you need to start making sure your successes are visible to managment. You also need to publicly compliment her work.

You also need to consider if you have been acting in such a way as to make things harder for her which is why she has chosen to go above you and if so stop that. Are you refusing to share information? Did you try to be friendly towards her?

The final possibility is one you can't fight and it is usualy best to move on. That is that the new woman is someone your boss is having an affair with or wants to have an affair with. The reason I strongly suspect this is because the new person seemed able to turn around opinons on you so quickly when you already had an established reputation.  That indicates she has more influence than a new employee normally has.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be an affair - they could be a family member or just a friend... while any nepotism is not professional, you do need to be careful making assertions - especially so if suggesting an affair.